# How to use wildcards with pkg-upgrade?

Tags: freebsd, package-management, wildcard, freebsd-ports

As an example, when I want to list all installed packages of `php70` I can just enter:

```
pkg info php70\*
```

But I cannot use the wildcard in this for `pkg upgrade`:

```
pkg upgrade php70\*
```

When I do get this message:

> pkg: php70* is not installed, therefore upgrade is impossible

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: `pkg upgrade -g php70\*` but for some reason with glob pkg suggest to install new packages matched by pattern. May be this is a bug.

Comment: I am quite sure it used to work, but sometimes memory plays tricks in you.

Comment: After reading your comment for the second time,,, maybe they disabled the wildcard because of this issue. (or feature)

Comment: You might consider using `xargs` when and if wildcards and regular expression are not supported by the utility.